# rowCallback and createdRow not highlighting row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I followed the documentation from the Jquery Datatable site, as well as SO posts,  to use rowCallback to highlight the row based on value.

```
let SET1 = $("#SET1").DataTable({
    "columns": columns,
    "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
    if ( data[0] == "jon" )
    {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
    }
    }
});
```

However, nothing I have tried rowCallback,createdRow or the fnrowCallback is making the row to change color.  Is it the way I'm loading the data?

below is my fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/czcz/qfr3xLq1/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rowCallback` is called once for each row. It is not an array, but an object. Try this:

```
let SET1 = $("#SET1").DataTable({
    "columns": columns,
    "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
    if ( data.name == "jon" )
    {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
    }
    }
});
```